# enlarge uploaded file size in webconfig using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, web-config

My case is when  I am uploading file with size more than 4mb i want to display a friendly message to the user but when i accross this limit it dose not give me an error instead it takes me to :

```
  Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
```

what i am doing to check on file size is like that :

```
   if (FU_EnglishFile.PostedFile.ContentLength > int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxUploadSize"]))
                            {
                                lbl_InvalidFileMsg.Visible = true;
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lbl_InvalidFileMsg.Visible = false;
}
```

where my file size from the web config is :

```
 <add key="MaxUploadSize" value="4194304" />
```

is there is any configuration should i set in the web config or something any help would be a appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to the question :

kindly set this tag in the web config

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
 </system.web>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use above code for less size like 3MB and then check the results.